Langsmith trace for gemini model
I am calling gemini API directly (not via langchain) and I have added the @traceable annotation to the function however when I go into langsmith it still says 0 tokens. What do I have to do to get it to trace properly. They provide a wrap_openai function which i'd like a similar for gemini.

I am seeing the same. Did you find a solution ?
